# Select dynamic ajax dropdown by name or id instead of class

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a dynamic Ajax drop down that changes value depending on the value selected in the previous drop-down. I currently have it working but for some reason it only works when I use the drop-down class name. When trying to use the name or id attribute it stops working.

I have tried using #category to get the value by the id name.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".category").change(function() {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "makes.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".makes").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });

    $(".makes").change(function() {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "models.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".models").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

**Drop-down HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
  <div class="select-dropdown">
    <select class="category" name="category" id="category">
      <option value="">All Vehicle Types</option>
      <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
      <option value="SUVs">SUVs</option>
      <option value="Trucks">Trucks</option>
      <option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
  <div class="select-dropdown">
    <select class="makes" name="makes" id="makes">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Any Make</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
  <div class="select-dropdown">
    <select class="models" name="models">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Any Model</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#category").change(function() {
    var id=$(this).val();
    alert(id)
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "makes.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#makes").html(html);
        } 
    });
});

$("#makes").change(function() {
    var id=$(this).val();
     alert(id)
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "models.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#models").html(html);
        } 
    });
   });
 });
</script>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
<div class="select-dropdown">
<select class="category" name="category" id="category">
  <option value="">All Vehicle Types</option>
  <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
  <option value="SUVs">SUVs</option>
  <option value="Trucks">Trucks</option>
  <option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
</select>
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
 <div class="select-dropdown">
 <select class="makes" name="makes" id="makes">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Any Make</option>
   <option value="2" selected="selected">Any Make1</option>
</select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
  <div class="select-dropdown">
  <select class="models" name="models" id="models">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Any Model</option>
   <option value="2" selected="selected">Any Model1</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  </div>
```

you can also use onchange function

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function test1(id_value){
    var id=id_value.value;
    alert(id)
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "makes.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#makes").html(html);
        } 
    });
}

function test2(id_value){
    var id=id_value.value;
    alert(id)
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "models.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#models").html(html);
        } 
    });
}

</script>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
<div class="select-dropdown">
<select class="category" name="category" id="category" onchange="test1(this)">
  <option value="">All Vehicle Types</option>
  <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
  <option value="SUVs">SUVs</option>
  <option value="Trucks">Trucks</option>
  <option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
<div class="select-dropdown">
<select class="makes" name="makes" id="makes" onchange="test2(this)">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Any Make</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Any Make1</option>
</select>
</div>
 </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
<div class="select-dropdown">
<select class="models" name="models" id="models">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Any Model</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Any Model1</option>
</select>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: didn't work. For some reason when I switch to choose from class name to id name it stops working. No other id name on the page has the same name.

Comment: just copy my code and check it in your editor then test it

Answer (score 0):

Your Code looks fine, by any chance you don't have another element in the rest of your code with category as its id or name? This could be whats causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic content you have to use

```
$(documemt).on('event name','selector',function(){ });
```

You code is like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('change',"#category",function() {
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "makes.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $(".makes").html(html);
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work. Don't know what it is. Only works when I choose the class name.